# How to display actual field with dropdowns instead of showing id?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models and two serializers

models:

```
class P4R(models.Model):
    p4r_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    psc_id = models.ForeignKey(BePsc, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='PSC Name')
    vbb_identifier = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='VBB Identifier')
    maturity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    capex_opex = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='CAPEX/OPEX')
    budget_item = models.ForeignKey(BudgetItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paying_interest = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Admin', null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vbb_identifier)

class P4RChangingFields(models.Model):
    p4r_variations_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vbb_identifier = models.ForeignKey(P4R, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='VBB Identifier')
    year_now = models.IntegerField(default=2023, verbose_name=f'Year {current_year}')
    year_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=35, decimal_places=25, verbose_name=f'Year {year_1_name}')
    year_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=35, decimal_places=25, verbose_name=f'Year {year_2_name}')
    year_3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=35, decimal_places=25, verbose_name=f'Year {year_3_name}')
    year_4 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=35, decimal_places=25, verbose_name=f'Year {year_4_name}')
    year_5 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=35, decimal_places=25, verbose_name=f'Year {year_5_name}')
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Admin', null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'P4R_VARIATIONS'
```

serializers:

```
class P4RSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = P4R
        fields = '__all__'


class P4RChangingFieldsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vbb_identifier = serializers.CharField(source='vbb_identifier.vbb_identifier')
    # vbb_identifier = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='vbb_identifier',  read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = P4RChangingFields
        fields = '__all__'
```

As you can see, vbb_identifier is the field that connects between the two table. when user create new row using P4R model, they will need to enter vbb_identifier in the form of strings ("ABC123").

the only relationship both table has is vbb_identifier and its one to many. one P4R object may have multiple P4RChangingFields object related to it.

and I have an API that supply P4RChangingFields data in my views.

the issue is, when the frontend team rendered my P4R Changing Fields the api can only show number of ids of P4R primary keys (p4r ids which are related to P4R Changing fields), but I dont want this since user cant make any sense of the pks and ids. they can only utilise the dropdowns if its represented in the vbb_identifier actual string value ('ABC123').

One more thing, the frontend would be a microservice and its not using django stacks. therefore I tried sending models str to them but it wont work.

I have been trying using this to solve this problem:

```
    vbb_identifier = serializers.CharField(source='vbb_identifier.vbb_identifier')
    # vbb_identifier = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='vbb_identifier',  read_only=True)
```

it solved one of my problem which is to show the actual value of vbb_identifier during a GET request, but when in POST or PUT method, I cannot do dropdowns, it will just be a textbox.

So I want the vbb_identifier to be represented in its own value, not its origin table pks, and it needs to be able to dropdowns.